# How common is it for US state political parties to ban association with Nazis?

Tags: united-states, parties, nazism

[Recently the Texas GOP has rejected a proposal to ban its party members from associating with Nazis.](https://www.texastribune.org/2023/12/02/texas-gop-antisemitism-resolution/)

My understanding is that this was an internal party resolution and not any type of legislation. I do not believe anyone from other parties was involved at all.

The executive committee removed from a pro-Israel resolution a clause stating that party members could not associate with anyone "known to espouse or tolerate antisemitism, pro-Nazi sympathies or Holocaust denial."

The clause was rejected 32-29:

> The ban, some argued, was akin to “Marxist” and “leftist” tactics, and would create guilt by association that could be problematic for the party, its leaders and candidates.

> “It could put you on a slippery slope,” said committee member Dan Tully.

**Do any state political parties in the US have explicit internal rules forbidding their members from associating with Nazis?**

I am interested in an apples-to-apples comparison of internal party rules, as opposed to legislation. National party rules would be also be interesting.

If the answer is yes, how many parties have such rules, and is the Texas Democratic Party one of them?

I tried to find an answer to this question, but my two favourite search engines only returned results related to this recent news regarding the Texas GOP. The articles I have read only discuss the aforementioned rejection by itself, with no context about any other parties or their own rules.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, political parties don't usually have many rules because it is impossible to actually enforce any political party rules, and impossible to kick someone out of the party. For example, there is no method for kicking someone out of a party. It simply doesn't exist. In fact, you can run, and win, an election as a member of a party that doesn't even want you as a member, much less a candidate.

So even if the rules did exist in theory, in practice they do not exist, not just for Nazism, but for really anything.

Instead, related organizations usually work as non profits, which will or won't fund candidates based on what they view as important, notably the two National Committees of the major parties, the DNC and RNC.

Comment: some references would make this a very good answer.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, and I agree that these rules would not be practically enforceable. However, since the Texas GOP was considering exactly this kind of rule, they can clearly exist. I really am hoping for an apples-to-apples comparison of whether such rules exist for any other parties, regardless of whether they are toothless.

Comment: It's very different to the situation in the UK where thousands of people have been [kicked out of the Labour party for associating with political movements seen as unacceptable](https://labourlist.org/2022/09/labour-nec-member-suspended-for-speaking-at-proscribed-groups-event/) (and this happens at regular intervals going back to the panic over far-left entryists in the 80s). So some references would be good, at least for those of us used to different forms of party organisation.

Answer (score -1):

Political Parties in the United States are, unlike many other party organizations in the world, are not government entities but private organizations and are not subject to the freedom of association clause that government organizations are.  It's entirely possible that within a state's chapter of a political party, the party can vote to not allow members who associate with other political ideologies.  That said, the vote was rejected because association does not mean agreement with political ideology.  For example, the classic trope of "racist grandparents" is an association that may be difficult for someone to avoid having through wholly innocent means (they are your parent's parents) but easy to reject their ideology.

It might also bring a case that someone who once supported the Nazi Party, but has since renounced them, may be punished in excess for knowing people who are Nazis still, due to past ties.

All this said, there exists the American Nazi Party, a real political party in the U.S... in the sense that it is a registered third party... but the likelihood of the party being successful is less than a lot of other more acceptable third parties.  Just because a Political Party can make members not associate by internal private rules, it does not mean that the U.S. can block a political party.

Comment: This in no way answers my question.

Comment: "racist grandparents" is very different from meeting with an avowed white supremacist.  The first is something an individual can't control, the second is definitely avoidable and a conscious choice.  [Fuentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Fuentes) does seem like a toxic maverick of little actual policy value, so reasonable politicians could reasonably be expected to steer clear.

Comment: Your first statement just vaguely says in many other parts of the world but please note that in democratic countries including all of Europe political parties are not government entities either but private organisations, usually non-profit or something similar.